# Airflow and Spark/Hadoop - Unique cluster or one for Airflow and other for Spark/Hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, airflow

I'm trying to figure out which is the best way to work with Airflow and Spark/Hadoop.
I already have a Spark/Hadoop cluster and I'm thinking about creating another cluster for Airflow that will submit jobs remotely to Spark/Hadoop cluster.

Any advice about it? Looks like it's a little complicated to deploy spark remotely from another cluster and that will create some file configuration duplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really only need to configure a `yarn-site.xml` file, I believe, in order for `spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client` to work. (You could try cluster deploy mode, but I think having the driver being managed by Airflow isn't a bad idea)

Once an Application Master is deployed within YARN, then Spark is running locally to the Hadoop cluster.

If you really want, you could add a `hdfs-site.xml` and `hive-site.xml` to be submitted as well from Airflow (if that's possible), but otherwise at least hdfs-site.xml files should be picked up from the YARN container classpath (not all NodeManagers could have a Hive client installed on them)

Comment: You can do that remotely, but you just need to configure access to your hive metastore, hadoop cluster and resource manager. Please also remember that spark is very sensitive to locallity. Therefore if your spark client is where Airflow and its different network. Then your jobs might be slower. I had issue like that, therefore I have Airflow in the same network where hadoop cluster.

Comment: Right, HDFS prefers local reads, and configuring Spark would be no different than any other Hadoop+Hive client

Comment: Ok, thank you for sharing your experience. I'm just looking for the best way to keep these frameworks working together like a couple. I'll keep them in two different cluster.

Comment: If you're using Ambari, you can install Spark and Hive clients onto Airflow workers. And keep configs in sync https://medium.com/@mykolamykhalov/integrating-apache-airflow-with-apache-ambari-ccab2c90173

Answer (score 1):

I prefer submitting Spark Jobs using SSHOperator and running `spark-submit` command which would save you from copy/pasting `yarn-site.xml`. Also, I would not create a cluster for Airflow if the only task that I perform is running Spark jobs, a single VM with `LocalExecutor` should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of options for remotely performing `spark-submit` via `Airflow`.

- [`Emr-Step`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/emr_add_steps_operator.py)
- [Apache-Livy](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html) (see [this](https://github.com/rssanders3/airflow-spark-operator-plugin/blob/master/spark_operator_plugin.py) for hint)
- [`SSH`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.py)

Do note that none of these are *plug-and-play* ready and you'll have to write your own operators to get things done.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54092691/3679900) for more details