# How to submit Spark jobs to EMR cluster from Airflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, airflow, amazon-emr

How can I establish a connection between EMR master cluster(created by Terraform) and Airflow. I have Airflow setup under AWS EC2 server with same SG,VPC and Subnet.

I need solutions so that Airflow can talk to EMR and execute Spark submit.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/build-a-concurrent-data-orchestration-pipeline-using-amazon-emr-and-apache-livy/

These blogs have understanding on execution after connection has been established.(Didn't help much)

In airflow I have made a connection using UI for AWS and EMR:-

[image]

Below is the code which will list the EMR cluster's which are Active and Terminated, I can also fine tune to get Active Clusters:-

```python
from airflow.contrib.hooks.aws_hook import AwsHook
import boto3
hook = AwsHook(aws_conn_id=‘aws_default’)
    client = hook.get_client_type(‘emr’, ‘eu-central-1’)
    for x in a:
        print(x[‘Status’][‘State’],x[‘Name’])
```

My question is - How can I update my above code can do Spark-submit actions

Comment: hi kally please specify what is the issue here that you are facing, what you have tried yet

Comment: Hi Kally, Can you share what resources you have created and which connection is not working?

Comment: @varnit I have updated the code which will list the All EMR Cluster, How can I know the master server IP from of single EMR cluster where I can submit my spark code

Comment: @pradeep I have updated the code which will list the All EMR Cluster, How can I know the master server IP from of single EMR cluster where I can submit my spark code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While it may not directly address your particular query, broadly, here are some ways you can trigger `spark-submit` on (*remote*) `EMR` via `Airflow`

1. **Use `Apache Livy`**

   - This solution is actually independent of remote server, i.e., `EMR`
   - [Here's](https://github.com/rssanders3/airflow-spark-operator-plugin/blob/master/spark_operator_plugin.py#L131) an example
   - The downside is that `Livy` is in early stages and its `API` appears [*incomplete* and *wonky*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51746286/3679900) to me
2. **Use `EmrSteps` `API`**

   - Dependent on remote system: `EMR`
   - Robust, but since it is inherently **async**, you will also need an `EmrStepSensor` (alongside `EmrAddStepsOperator`)
   - On a single `EMR` cluster, you cannot have more than one steps running simultaneously (although some [*hacky* workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53156794/3679900) exist)
3. **Use `SSHHook` / `SSHOperator`**

   - Again independent of remote system
   - Comparatively easier to get started with
   - If your `spark-submit` command involves a lot of arguments, building that command (programmatically) can become cumbersome

---

**EDIT-1**

There seems to be another straightforward way

4. **Specifying remote `master`-IP**

   - Independent of remote system
   - [Needs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37649944/3679900) modifying *Global Configurations / Environment Variables*
   - See [**@cricket_007**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52013958/3679900) for details

---

Useful links

- This one is from [**@Kaxil Naik**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5691525/kaxil) himself: [Is there a way to submit spark job on different server running master](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53344713/3679900)
- [Spark job submission using Airflow by submitting batch POST method on Livy and tracking job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54228651/spark-job-submission-using-airflow-by-submitting-batch-post-method-on-livy-and-t)
- [Remote spark-submit to YARN running on EMR](https://medium.com/@tamizhgeek/remote-spark-submit-toyarn-running-on-emr-9804b89d82d2)

Comment: Thank you for the info. I have EMR clusters getting created by AWS ASG, I need a breakthrough where I can pull single EMR Master running cluster from AWS(Currently we are running 4 cluster in single Environment). I mean to say, How can I specify in which EMR cluster I need to do Spark-submit

Comment: **@Kally** if you take the `EmrStep` route, the **cluster-id** a.k.a. `JobFlowId` will be needed to specify which cluster to submit to. Otherwise, you will have to obtain the **private-IP of that cluster's `master`** (which i think you can easily do [via `boto3`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.list_instances)). While I'm a novice with `AWS` infrastructure, i believe `IAM Role`s would come handy for authorization (i assume you already know that)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53743370/3679900) for hints on how to modify `Airflow`'s built-in `operator`s to work over `SSH`

Answer (score 1):

As you have created EMR using Terraform, then you get the master IP as `aws_emr_cluster.my-emr.master_public_dns`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. How can I authenticate to this master IP server and do spark-submit – Kally 18 hours ago