# submit spark job from local to emr ssh setup

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, spark-submit

I am new to spark. I want to submit a spark job from local to a remote EMR cluster.
I am following the link here to set up all the prerequisites: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-submit-spark-job-remote-cluster/

here is the command as below:

```
spark-submit --class mymain --deploy-mode client --master yarn myjar.jar
```

Issue: sparksession creation is not able to be finished with no error. Seems an access issue.

From the aws document, we know that by given the master with yarn, yarn uses the config files I copied from EMR to know where is the master and slaves (yarn-site.xml). 
As my EMR cluster is located in a VPC, which need a special ssh config to access, how could I add this info to yarn so it can access to the remote cluster and submit the job?

Answer (score 1):

I think the resolution proposed in aws link is more like - create your local spark setup with all dependencies.
If you don't want to do local spark setup, I would suggest easier way would be, you can use:
 
1. Livy: for this you emr setup should have livy installed. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022129/how-to-submit-spark-jobs-to-emr-cluster-from-airflow/54092691#54092691), [this](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html), [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/151164/how-to-submit-spark-application-through-livy-rest.html) and you should be able to infer from [this](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/programmatic-api.html)

2. EMR ssh: this requires you to have [aws-cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html) installed locally, cluster id and pem file used while creating emr cluster. Check [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/ssh.html)
Eg. `aws emr ssh --cluster-id j-3SD91U2E1L2QX --key-pair-file ~/.ssh/mykey.pem --command 'your-spark-submit-command'` (This prints command output on console though)